# What's the difference in these VB Implementations?

Tags: .net, vb.net, exception

**Aim To Achieve :**
I want to add the prevMonth's name at the end of each member of the list.

I have 2 implementations of the same thing, 1 is working but other is giving exception.

Working Code :

```
prevMonthSheetNames = addMonth(monthlySheetNames, prevMonth)

Private Function addMonth(ByVal list As IEnumerable(Of String), ByVal month As String) As List(Of String)
    Return list.Select(Function(name) String.Concat(name) + " (" + month + ")").ToList()
End Function
```

Implementation with Exception :

```
prevMonthSheetNames = monthlySheetNames.Select(Function(name) String.Concat(name) + " (" + prevMonth + ")").ToList()
```

> Error : Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Object)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'

If I remove .ToList() from above, then :

> Exception: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Please help, What is going on - It seems to be same, but 1 gives error and other doesn't ?

Declaration of `monthlySheetNames` :

```
Private monthlySheetNames As New List(Of String)(New String() {"Salary", "Budget", "Loans"})
```

Comment: Can you include the declaration for monthlySheetNames please. Do you have option explicit/strict turned on in your code?

Comment: OK... I am adding that !

Comment: option explicit/strict - I don't know how to use this. So, I didn't used this, it must be what its by default.

Comment: What is the end goal of your code?  It's a bit of a mess right now, if you tell us what you want we might be able to decipher it better

Comment: I just want to add the month's name at the end of each member of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in your second example the anonymous function returns an `Object` instead of `String` and therefore the casting fails.

First, go to project properties and make sure [**Option Strict**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) is **On** on the **Compile** tab of **Project Properties**.

Then, look closely at `prevMonth` declaration.
How do you assign it? What is its type? Are you sure it is a `String`?

It may also help to play around with the [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx) to ensure it returns a `String`. Right it is a bit of a mess:

```
Function(name) String.Concat(name) + " (" + prevMonth + ")"
```

`String.Concat` concatenates its *parameters* and you only give it one. This call is useless.
Also, if `prevMonth` isn't really a `String`, I'm not sure how VB .NET will apply `+` operators.

After all, it's much simpler (and safer) to use `String.Format` as [suggested by Smudge002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980703/whats-the-difference-in-these-vb-implementations/6981077#6981077):

```
Function(name) String.Format("{0} ({1})", name, prevMonth)
```

At the very least, you'll be sure it *does* return a `String`.

Comment: Thanks for the mention @Dan.  +1 for being a bit more verbose. Perhaps you could link docs for [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs(v=VS.100).aspx)? =)

Comment: No probs. Also, how do you do that (link to someone else's answer)?  Pinch the link from the user's profile > activity tab?  Or is there an easier way?

Comment: You did it.. can't believe it.. Wow.. String.Format worked out.
Thanks.. !!

Comment: @Smudge002: there's a `link` link below each answer, it'll give you a  popup with permalink.

Comment: @Dan - the simple things are so simple once you know how. =)  Thanks muchly

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be related to your use of the '+' operator. You should be using '&' for concatenation in VB.Net. Also, the use of the String.Concat function is redundant - it will not have any effect. Try this.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

prevMonthSheetNames = monthlySheetNames.Select(Function(name) name & " (" & prevMonth & ")").ToList()
```

I am not sure what the difference between the two versions is. Possibly though, it is due to an implicit conversion of the parameter values. I have included statements in the code sample that will ensure that both Option Strict and Option Explicit are enabled. This might help to pick up such problems.

Comment: No, It didn't helped.. with `.ToList()` it gave error as in the question. Also, using `&` and removing `String.Concat` didn't helped either. Still things are same !

Comment: I added option explicit and strict statements. Could you try these please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
Public Function GetSheetNamesForMonth(byval sheetNames As IEnumerable(Of String), Byval monthName As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Return sheetNames.Select(Function(n) String.Format("{0}({1})", n, monthName))
End Function
```

Comment: I want to do it with the second way which is not working, without a function.

Comment: @Yugal - if you don't want the function, remove everything after the word "`Return`" and rename the variables as required.  i.e. `prevMonthSheetNames = monthlySheetNames.Select(Function(n) String.Format("{0}({1})", n, prevMonthName))`/  It does the same thing, whether in a function or not...